# Which is the better practice to initialise activity-wide member variables?

Tags: android

Is it better practice to initialise these sort of variables in `onCreate()`, or before it? For example, is this:

```
public class Farts extends Activity {
    private List<String> mFartHistory = new ArrayList<String>(R.array.fart_history);
    private ListView mFartView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fart_view);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // blablablalbalblabal
    }
}
```

or this:

```
public class Farts extends Activity {
    private List<String> mFartHistory;
    private ListView mFartView;

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedPoopooState) {
        mFartHistory = new ArrayList<String>(R.array.fart_history);
        mFartView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fart_view);
        // blablbalablbabalal
    }
}
```

better practice?

Or does it even matter, that it's simply just a preference or something?

Comment: Farts....??This activity will blow up everything... :O

Comment: what kind of array initialization is this dear??? Please go through some newBie tutorials before posting such questions. You can always access the string.xml ids inside onCreate()

Comment: @nobalG It's a code smell.

Comment: @laalto for a moment I felt it..(and I am sure you did too)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you can call methods of the superclass `Activity`, including any `Context` methods only in `onCreate()` or later.

For example, calling `findViewById()` before `onCreate()` will fail with `NullPointerException`.

Therefore the latter form is preferable.

For the initialization that doesn't require calling activity methods, it doesn't really matter where you do it.

I understand the code you posted are examples but remember to call `super.onCreate()`, and call `setContentView()` before `findViewById()`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about having to call setContentView before calling findViewById. Dang. Also I was kinda trying to take a few liberties in my ask so I left out setContentView and super.onCreate() on purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets take yout example:

```
private List<String> mFartHistory = new ArrayList<String>(R.array.fart_history);
private ListView mFartView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fart_view);
```

If you try to make the initialization this way, the result will be:

```
mFartHistory --> ArrayList
mFartView    --> NullPointerException
```

Why? Because the code above is executed when the object is created. So the `List` will be properly initialized but the result of calling `findViewById` (in the point of creation of the object) will throw a `NullPointerException`. This is because this method searches in the layout of the activity but the content layout hasn't been set yet. So the assignment of the `ListView` must be done after the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` is called.

So the conclusion is that you have to assign `View` fields after the content was set otherwise they will remain `null`.

Now about your question: which one is better. There is no better or worse. It depends on your code style. I prefer to do all the assignments in the `onCreate` method when we are talking about `Activity` classes. If it is a POJO, I prefer to do this in the constructor.

Comment: Actually it will NPE straight away since the activity doesn't yet have a `Window`.

Comment: Haha yeah I do know about putting setContentView  in as well, just kinda took a few liberties in my ask is all. Anyway thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about better practice for **in both case** your application will crash. You will get a `NullPointerException` for that `ListView`. Because you are not calling `super.onCreate(savedPoopooState);` and haven't used `setContentView(R.layout.ur_layout_name)` or `setContentView(anyView)` before calling `findViewById`. You have to do like this

```
public class Farts extends Activity {
    private List<String> mFartHistory;
    private ListView mFartView;

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedPoopooState) {
        super.onCreate(savedPoopooState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ur_layout_name);//layout which consists that listview
        mFartHistory = new ArrayList<String>(R.array.fart_history);
        mFartView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fart_view);
        // blablbalablbabalal
    }
}
```

Or you can programmatically create that `ListView` and **setContentView(listView)** into `Activity`

**Forget about your first case. It will definitely crash as you are calling findViewById() before setContentView(R.layout.ur_layout_name)**

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about how you need to first call setContentView before initialising any view objects. Welp, thanks anyway!